# Getting SAML Token from SharePoint

Tags: web-services, authentication, claims-based-auth, adfs, security-token-service

I have a SharePoint running on SAML security and I'm creating a SharePoint web part to interact with an external system (kind of connector), the communacation is made using SOAP Web Services, to authenticate user on the external system I must send to it the SAML Token.

Is there any method to get SAML token from SharePoint for an authenticated user ?